# Cannot deploy app React-Native missing organization in Manifest

Tags: deployment, package, react-native, android-manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.db3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
```

Note that the package is "com.db3".  Of course this would not be unique because the organization (url) isn't included.  In my past Android programming, the package would be:

```
package="com.myCompany.db3"
```

where `<myCompany>` is my organization making the package unique.

The guide to deployment is sparse, is there a way to set this up from the get go?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deploy react-native applications is with [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/). You can see a detailed description of how to set it up [in this blog post](https://dbanck.svbtle.com/part-2-android-with-fastlane-supply)